# How can I map UIDs to user names using Perl library functions?

Tags: perl, unix

I'm looking for a way of mapping a uid (unique number representing a system user) to a user name using Perl.

Please don't suggest `grep`ing /etc/passwd :)

**Edit**

As a clarification, I wasn't looking for a solution that involved reading /etc/passwd *explicitly*. I realize that under the hood any solution would end up doing this, but I was searching for a library function to do it for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard function [`getpwuid`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpwuid.html), just like the same C function, gets user information based on its ID.  No `use`s needed:

```
my ($name) = getpwuid(1000);
print $name,"\n";
```

Although it eventually reads `/etc/passwd` file, using standard interfaces is much more clear for other users to see, let alone it saves you some keystrokes.

Comment: Ok, out of curiosity I made a small script. I call `getpwuid(1000);` **5 times** in a row. *Literally* in a row. Then I `strace` and grep the output. What is this ? Could it be that it calls "`open`" **5 times** ? Yes! And that is for the same user. Now I see, 4 I/O calls extra are TOTALLY worth the extra keystrokes.

Comment: @nc3b If I was interested in performance I would be doing this in C. I'm optimizing for development time instead of resource usage. (nb, Perl is the best language for this in my current environment)

Comment: @Mike You know best what your priorities are. In my opinion cutting on I/O access is not optimization, it's basic. I mean, run `getpwuid(1000)` in a loop and you'll see good old linear running time. Anyway, I am just glad I did this test, I learned something today :-)

Comment: `getpwuid` cannot assume that the `/etc/passwd` file has not changed since the last call, however unlikely that may be.

Comment: mobrule is right. `/etc/passwd` can change at any time. If you're worried about performance for user lookups, just memoize the results of `getpwuid` (and be prepared to accept the consequences!)

Comment: you can always use the timestamp of /etc/passwd as basis for assuming your cache is outdated

Answer (score 1):

Read /etc/passwd and hash the UID to login name.

Edit:

```
$uid   = getpwnam($name);
$name  = getpwuid($num);
$name  = getpwent();
$gid   = getgrnam($name);
$name  = getgrgid($num);
$name  = getgrent();
```

As you can see, regardless of which one you pick, the system call reads from /etc/passwd (see [this](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/getpwnam.html) for reference)

Comment: Don't down vote. Regardless of what you do, eventually you (or a system call) will read and hash from /etc/passwd.

Comment: And regardless of what file you grep, the CPU will eventually execute assembly commands, so why just not code everything in assembler?  So you `grep` files in your own way, and then you wonder, [How did Perl gain a reputation for being a write-only language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702728/how-did-perl-gain-a-reputation-for-being-a-write-only-language)

Comment: Yes down vote:  Reading the file directly should *never* be the first tool in one's box.  A good answer would have presented the built-ins as the default option and alluded to reading `/etc/passwd` as a possible optimization.
Also:  Telling people how to vote?  Laughable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would suggest building a hash based on /etc/passwd :-) This should work well as the user ids are required to be unique.

Comment: Any constructive feedback ? How else can you get information about users / user ids ?

Comment: Because I'm looking for a perl library that will do this for me. I understand that at some point it involves reading from /etc/password.

Comment: I fail to see where in your question you suggested this :-) I also don't quite get the benefits of a "library" to do this. It's a *file* man, do you need libraries to read colon separated values ?

Comment: i thought it was suggested with my cute remark near the end. although i guess i should have been more clear.

Comment: and, yes having a library is always more valuable, even if the task is trivial.

Comment: Also, the library calls may be implemented to use other databases like YP/NIS/NIS+/LDAP/etc. in addition or in the place of `/etc/passwd`. Not all systems are standalone.